# Good practice for handling naturally JOINed results across an application

Tags: php, mysql, database, join, database-design

I'm working on an existing application that uses some JOIN statements to create "immutable" objects (i.e. the results are always JOINed to create a processable object - results from only one table will be meaningless).

For example:

```
SELECT r.*,u.user_username,u.user_pic FROM articles r INNER JOIN users u ON u.user_id=r.article_author WHERE ...
```

will yield a result of type, let's say, `ArticleWithUser` that is necessary to display an article with the author details (like a blog post).

Now, I need to make a table `featured_items` which contains the columns`item_type` (article, file, comment, etc.) and `item_id` (the article's, file's or comment's id), and query it to get a list of the featured items of some type.

Assuming tables other than `articles` contain whole objects that do not need JOINing with other tables, I can simply pull them with a dynamicially generated query like

```
SELECT some_table.* FROM featured_items RIGHT JOIN some_table ON some_table.id = featured_items.item_id WHERE featured_items.type = X
```

But what if I need to get a featured item from the aforementioned type `ArticleWithUser`? I cannot use the dynamically generated query because the syntax will not suit two JOINs.

So, my question is: is there a better practice to retrieve results that are always combined together? Maybe do the second JOIN on the application end?

Or do I have to write special code for each of those combined results types?

Thank you!

Comment: sure, if mysql can't `handle` it, then slam your immutable together with  middleware. `Handle` being defined as what is possible in mysql including what you don't know.

Comment: Mysql can definitely handle it, but the queries for that will be too ad hoc (at least 2 JOINs, explicitly naming fields etc.). I'm looking for a more maintainable solution that will be as close as possible to treating JOINed tables as a single table.

Comment: like a view. check it out :>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a view can be thot of as like a table for the faint of heart.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html

views can incorporate `joins`. and `other views`. keep in mind that upon creation, they take a snapshot of the columns in existence at that time on underlying tables, so `Alter Table` stmts adding columns to those tables are `not` picked up in select *.

Comment: Yes! Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. Are views widely used? If not, is there a reason for it? It's the first time I run into them.

Comment: they are heavily used imo. others can offer their experience. we would use them for peeps (often non-techies) that were stakeholders in the system. Such peeps were not thrilled about doing joins, cranked out reports, and putting it together wrong would be egg on their face in a meeting. so they begged for views. also, techies got a little sick of doing the same sorta thing with a slight modification needed. that sorta thing

Answer (score 1):

An old article which I consider required reading on the subject of MySQL Views:
[By Peter Zaitsev](https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/08/12/mysql-view-as-performance-troublemaker/)

To answer your question as to whether they are widely used, they are a major part of the database developer's toolkit, and in some situations offer significant benefits, which have more to do with indexing than with the nature of views, *per se*.

Comment: The article is interesting but:

- Hasn't this changed in the 8 years since 2007?

- How should views be optimized then? It doesn't say.